# Get to super declaration using Java's compiler API

Tags: java, javac, javac-compiler-plugin

Say I am writing annotation processor or compiler plugin, how can I get form `com.sun.source.tree.MethodTree`(/`JCTree.JCMethodDecl`) or `Symbol.MethodSymbol` to their "super" (if exists), e.g. if I try to compile

```java
class A {
     public void foo() {}
}
class B extends A {
     @Override public void foo() {}
}
```

I want to do something like:

```java
public class printSuper extends ...
        implements TaskListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void finished(TaskEvent taskEvt) {
        if (taskEvt.getKind() != TaskEvent.Kind.ANALYZE) {
            return;
        }
        taskEvt.getCompilationUnit().accept(new TreeScanner<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void visitMethod(MethodTree methodDecl, Void v) {
                var zuper = magicToGetSuperDecl(methodDecl);
                // for A.foo > null/exception/some equivalent
                // for B.foo > A.foo
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

I tried to use the `TreePath` of `methodDecl`, but the best I got from there is the `javax.lang.model.element.Element` of the class of the method, I tried to use `trees.getPath(zuperElement)` I sometimes get `null`.

Also, from `trees.getPath(zuperElement).getLeaf()` I can get to list of methods the super class has, but I couldn't find a good way to get the specific method I from the super class.